# Lottie and scalemode settings for the web

Tags: javascript, json, animation, lottie

We're using [lottie](https://airbnb.io/lottie/web/getting-started.html) for some slick animations but I can't find any documentation on what options there are for **scaleMode** in lottie.

```
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('bm'),
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  path: 'data.json',
  rendererSettings: {
    scaleMode: 'noScale'
  }
})
```

Does anyone know what the other options might be? Searching the js file it loads, scaleMode isn't actually included in the text.

Comment: while `scaleMode` is shown in the docs, it doesn't appear to be used in the code: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/blob/5b28a2190267e5b3c81c1df1e8fb93ac3d257c98/player/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js#L1

Answer (score 1):

`scaleMode` has been replaced by `preserveAspectRatio` and it supports the same options than the svg attribute.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio